# Help on Proof involving integrals

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Good night.

I'm starting to learn proofs and I'm facing the following question.

Given the linear function $f(x)$, prove that $[\int_{0}^{1} f(x)\,dx]^2 < \int_{0}^{1}[f(x)] ^2dx$

As $f(x)$ is a linear function, I represented it as $f(x) = ax + b$. How to proceed with the proof now ?

Comment: When $a=2$, $b=2$, the inequality does not hold...

Comment: Do you want the RHS to be $[f^2 (x)]$? Perhaps you are thinking of [Cauchy Schwarz, integral version](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy–Schwarz_inequality#L2)?

Comment: There was a little typo in the inequality, fixed now. I'm sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be an arbitrary linear function, namely $f(x) = ax + b$.  It follows:
$$\begin{align}
\left[\int_0^1f(x)\,dx\right]^2 &= \left[\int_0^1 ax+b\,dx\right]^2 \\
&= \left[\frac{ax^2}{2} + bx \Bigg|_0^1 \right]^2\\
&= \left[\frac{a}{2} + b\right]^2 \\
&= \frac{a^2}{4} + ab + b^2
\end{align}$$
It also follows:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1[f(x)]^2\,dx &= \int_0^1[(ax+b)]^2\,dx \\
&= \int_0^1[(ax+b)]^2\,dx \\
&= \frac{a^2x^3}{3}+\frac{2abx^2}{2}+b^2x \Bigg|_0^1\\
&= \frac{a^2}{3}+ab+b^2\\
\end{align}$$

From here, it should be pretty obvious...